# Other Key Mold uses Terraria

Tags: terraria, terraria-console

I have been playing Terraria (Console) for quite some time now, and have collected a few key molds. I've opened the Hallow, Frost, and Corruption chests and only have 2 left (Jungle and Crimson), but have two Hallowed key molds left over. I really don't want these for anything, crafting a key from them would just be a waste.

Is possible to sell them, or would it be best if I keep them for any other uses they have, or that may be implemented?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Key molds have no intended use other than to craft their respective keys.

Key molds have just a single, very straightforward purpose. Saving up spares won't do anything except allow you to make more keys to open similar chests in new worlds (or to make people who are grinding for them jealous).

As for possible future uses: update 1.3.0.1 (currently only on the Desktop version of the game) removes key molds from the game and simply has the biome keys themselves drop from enemies. Any existing key molds are automatically replaced with their respective keys ([Source](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Biome_Key_Mold)). If this change is brought to other versions of the game, obviously the Key Molds will have no alternate uses.

Even if the other versions of the game don't get this particular change...developer intent as to whether they will ever have another use is off-topic for Stack Exchange Gaming, but simply looking at it logically and considering what they are and what they're used for, it seems unlikely they will ever be given additional uses.

Comment: Can I sell them to the NPCs?

Comment: They won't be used for anything else, and will be swapped to keys when 1.3 goes to console. Selling duplicates is recommended.

Comment: @Ev1l0rd Oh right, I had it backwards in my head. I'll update accordingly.

Comment: @GeorgeWillcox The Wiki doesn't list a sale price, though that doesn't necessarily mean "no." That said, I don't have any biome keys, nor a version of the game with key molds, so you're in a better position to answer that than I am. =P